# A matrix has a real logarithm if it has a positive spectrum.

Tags: matrices, reference-request, logarithms, online-resources

The title is a proposition I read in my notes that's left with no proof. Where can I read one?

Comment: Are we finite dimensional here?

Comment: @ncmathsadist Yes, we are. Where can I read on infinite dimentional matrixes?

Comment: @George Hilbert spaces.

Comment: @MyUserIsThis I beg your pardon?

Comment: @George Hilbert spaces can be of infinite dimensions, for example the linear space of all polynomials has infinite (countable) dimension. Endomorphisms in this space could be represented by an infinite matrix. You can read this to begin with: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)#Infinite_matrices

Comment: @George I'm sorry for not being more explicit in the first place, I should have supposed that if you were asking you didn't know... Hope you like that topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost trivial. Consider a $k\times k$ Jordan block $J_k(\lambda)$, where $\lambda>0$. Then $J_k(\lambda)$ is the Jordan form of $e^{J_k(\log\lambda)}$ and hence $J_k(\lambda)=Pe^{J_k(\log\lambda)}P^{-1}=e^{PJ_k(\log\lambda)P^{-1}}$ for some real invertible $P$. That is, $PJ_k(\log\lambda)P^{-1}$ is a real logarithm of $J_k(\lambda)$.

If you really need a reference, see

> Walter J. Culver, *[On the existence and uniqueness of the real logarithm of a matrix](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1966-017-05/S0002-9939-1966-0202740-6/S0002-9939-1966-0202740-6.pdf)*, Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society, 17(5): 1146-1151, 1966,

although the main focus of this paper is placed on some more interesting cases than yours. You may also see Nick Higham's [Functions of Matrices: Theory and Computation](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~higham/fm/) or Horn and Johnson's [Topics in Matrix Analysis](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=LeuNXB2bl5EC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_atb#v=onepage&q&f=false). There is a good chance that these reference books would contain the theorems you need.